# Как соединить в один два столбца dataframe pandas "расческой"?

Tags: python, pandas

Например, есть такой тестовый датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ivan', 'Vasya', 'Kolya'], 'A_1':['02', '03', '01'], 'A_2':['02', '07', '11']})
```

Исходный вид:

```
Name    A_1 A_2
Ivan    02  02
Vasya   03  07
Kolya   01  11
```

Конечный вид:

```
Name   A
Ivan   02
Ivan   02
Vasya  03
Vasya  07
Kolya  01
Kolya  11
```

Буду очень благодарна за помощь

UPD:

Исправила про Колю,  как заметил @inquirer в комментарии.
И поняла, что слишком упростила задачу в примере — на самом деле колонок больше, чем две, например, так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ivan', 'Vasya', 'Kolya'], 
'Age':['50', '20', '45'],
'A_1':['02', '03', '01'], 
'A_2':['02', '07', '11'],
'B_1':['07', '15', '08'], 
'B_2':['35', '15', '12'],
'C_1':['02', '07', '13'], 
'C_2':['05', '06', '13']})
```

То есть вот исходные данные:

```
Name    Age A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2
Ivan    50  02  02  07  35  02  05
Vasya   20  03  07  15  15  07  06
Kolya   45  01  11  08  12  13  13
```

А вот итоговые:

```
Name    Age A   B   C   
Ivan    50  02  07  02  
Ivan    50  02  35  05  
Vasya   20  03  15  07
Vasya   20  07  15  06
Kolya   45  01  08  13
Kolya   45  11  12  13
```

Comment: Наверняка есть какая-то специальная функция для этого, но это нужно MaxU или другого какого гуру ждать, который точно знает )

Comment: Вопрос у Вас точно один Коля = 01. В конечном виде есть только Коля = 02?

Comment: @inquirer верно, исправила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ivan', 'Vasya', 'Kolya'], 'A_1':['02', '03', '01'], 'A_2':['02', '07', '11']})
    
    f = pd.Series(df['A_1'].values, index= df['Name'].values)
    a = pd.Series(df['A_2'].values, index= df['Name'].values)
    b = pd.concat([f, a], axis=0)
    
    print(b.sort_index())#сортировка по имени
    """
    Ivan     02
    Ivan     02
    Kolya    01
    Kolya    11
    Vasya    03
    Vasya    07
    """
    print(b.sort_values())#сортировка по значениям
    """
    Kolya    01
    Ivan     02
    Ivan     02
    Vasya    03
    Vasya    07
    Kolya    11
    """
```

Не при сортировке идет сначала Коля, а нужно, чтобы Вася(так в распечатке). Если правильно понимаю?
Уточните нужна сортировка или сначала в списке Вася, а потом Коля?

Comment: Порядок имен не важен, главное, чтобы одинаковые были подряд :) Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Тогда по имени сортируйте и все)

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'],
                    'Name': ['ABC', 'PQR', 'DEF', 'GHI']})
  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['B05', 'B06', 'B07', 'B08'],
                    'Name': ['XYZ', 'TUV', 'MNO', 'JKL']})
  
  
frames = [df1, df2]
  
result = pd.concat(frames)
result
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я думала об этом, но, наверное, я привела слишком упрощенный пример. На самом деле колонок, которые надо соединить -12 штук (в 6 колонок), а которые надо дублировать - 8. Разбивать большой датафрейм на 12 и потом соединять попарно, а потом в один общий - выглядит нерационально.

Comment: @ДарьяКилина А зачем попарно? И `concat` и другие функции соединения работают с любым кол-вом датафреймов, не нужно их попарно соединять, можно все сразу.

Comment: @CrazyElf если все сразу, то получится всё в виде датафрейма из двух колонок, где в первой будут имена повторяться 12 раз)  - я пояснила в UPD

Answer (score 2):

Наверняка можно как-то проще и у меня порядок строк другой получается, но сами данные какие нужно:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': df['Name'].to_list() * 2, 
    'A': df['A_1'].to_list() + df['A_2'].to_list()
})
```

Вывод:

```
    Name    A
0   Ivan    02
1   Vasya   03
2   Kolya   01
3   Ivan    02
4   Vasya   07
5   Kolya   11
```

Comment: Спасибо! В целом осталось добавить sort_values(by=['Name']) и все ок)